# Converting String using specific encoding to get just one character

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm on this frustrating journey trying to get a specific character from a Swift string. I have an Objective-C function, something like

```
- ( NSString * ) doIt: ( char ) c
```

that I want to call from Swift.

This `c` is eventually passed to a C function in the back that does the weightlifting here but this function gets tripped over when `c` is `&nbsp;` or `A0`.

Now I have two questions (apologies SO).

1. I am trying to use different encodings, especially the `ASCII` variants, hoping one would convert `&nbsp;` (`A0`) to spcae (`20` or dec 32). The verdict seems to be that I need to hardcode this but if there is a failsafe, non-hardcoded way I'd like to hear about it!
2. I am really struggling with the conversion itself. How do I access a specific character using a specific encoding in Swift?

a) I can use

```
s.utf8CString[ i ]
```

but then I am bound to `UTF8`.

b) I can use something like

```
let s = "\u{a0}"
let p = UnsafeMutablePointer < CChar >.allocate ( capacity : n )

defer
{
    p.deallocate()
}

// Convert to ASCII
NSString ( string : s ).getCString ( p,
        maxLength : n,
        encoding  : CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding ( CFStringBuiltInEncodings.ASCII.rawValue ) )

// Hope for 32
let c = p[ i ]
```

but this seems overkill. The string is converted to `NSString` to apply the encoding and I need to allocate a pointer, all just to get a single character.

c) Here it seems Swift String's `withCString` is the man for the job, but I can not even get it to compile. Below is what Xcode's completion gives but even after fiddling with it for a long time I am still stuck.

```
// How do I use this
// ??
s.withCString ( encodedAs : _UnicodeEncoding.Protocol ) { ( UnsafePointer < FixedWidthInteger & UnsignedInteger > ) -> Result in
// ??
}
```

TIA

Comment: “Nonbreaking space” U+A0 and “Space” U+20 are different characters, so this is not an encoding problem. You could simply replace one by the other before extracting the C characters.

Comment: @MartinR thanks - is what I do at present. But still, to get just one char from a Swift string in a given encoding ...

Comment: Are there more problematic characters? What about umlauts, symbols, emojis, ...? How would you expect those to be handled?

Comment: Another question: It the problem that the C function chokes on A0, or that it is converted to UTF-8 (C2 A0)?

Comment: @MartinR I don't really have that *umlaut* problem but if I run into it I suppose more hardcoded replacements using e.g. ```NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch```. The string here represents a locale sensitive separator so I expect something like comma, space, semi etc. On the other question. The C chokes on A0 yes. So I need not really bother with the rest of the question, but I would love to see a real world example of ```withCString```. I've seen some simple ones on the net, nothing that uses an encoding. Then I can play around with it a bit and see if it will work or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `withCString()` methods: [`withCString(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1538904-withcstring) calls the given closure with a pointer to the contents of the string, represented as a null-terminated sequence of UTF-8 code units. Example:

```
// An emulation of your Objective-C method.
func doit(_ c: CChar) {
    print(c, terminator: " ")
}

let s = "a\u{A0}b"
s.withCString { ptr in
    var p = ptr
    while p.pointee != 0 {
        doit(p.pointee)
        p += 1
    }
}
print()

// Output: 97 -62 -96 98
```

Here `-62 -96` is the *signed* character representation of the UTF-8 sequence `C2 A0` of the NO-BREAK SPACE character U+00A0.

If you just want to iterate over all UTF-8 characters of the string sequentially then you can simply use the `.utf8` view. The (unsigned) `UInt8` bytes must be converted to the corresponding (signed) `CChar`:

```
let s = "a\u{A0}b"
for c in s.utf8 {
        doit(CChar(bitPattern: c))
}
print()
```

I am not aware of a method which transforms U+00A0 to a “normal” space character, so you have to do that manually. With

```
let s = "a\u{A0}b".replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{A0}", with: " ")
```

the output of the above program would be `97 32 98`.

The [`withCString(encodedAs:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2905061-withcstring) method calls the given closure with a pointer to the contents of the string, represented as a null-terminated sequence of code units. Example:

```
let s = "a\u{A0}b€"
s.withCString(encodedAs: UTF16.self) { ptr in
    var p = ptr
    while p.pointee != 0 {
        print(p.pointee, terminator: " ")
        p += 1
    }
}
print()

// Output: 97 160 98 8364
```

This method is probably of limited use for your purpose because it can only be used with `UTF8`, `UTF16` and `UTF32`.

For other encodings you can use the `data(using:)` method. It produces a `Data` value which is a sequence of `UInt8` (an unsigned type). As above, these must be converted to the corresponding signed character:

```
let s = "a\u{A0}b"
if let data = s.data(using: .isoLatin1) {
    data.forEach {
        doit(CChar(bitPattern: $0))
    }
}
print()

// Output: 97 -96 98
```

Of course this may fail if the string is not representable in the given encoding.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I appreciate your efforts. Especially the ```withCString``` example and also the extra mile you went with the data one.

Comment: @skaak: You are welcome. I have added another method `for c in s.utf8 { ... }` which is even simpler to use and may be sufficient for your purpose.